# Так с чем едят Java Beans?

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Пока читал разрозненную информацию по серверным фреймворкам, все время натыкался на понятие Java Beans, и везде как бы подразумевалось, что это понятие читающему известно.

Гугл говорит что-то про компонентную среду, соглашение об именовании классов и конструктор без параметров (в общем-то, POJO только с Bean суффиксом), но хотелось бы понять, как и где эти Bean'ы используют, в контексте сервлетов? 
Если понятие слишком широкое, чтобы привести конкретный пример, подскажите в словах где бы такой класс использовался и как?

Comment: Плюс за каламбур.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Понятие действительно очень широкое, но как правило, никакой Америки оно не открывает.
**Java Beans** - просто стандарт. Обычный объект обычного java класса, который должен соблюдать следующие основные правила:

1. У класса должен быть конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров).
2. Поля должны быть доступны через методы доступа get (аксессоры) и set (мутаторы).
3. Класс должен быть сериализуемым (реализовывать интерфейс java.io.Serializable).

Никаких ограничений по именованию класса (типа постфикса Bean) спецификацией не предусмотрено. Так, же многие говорят, что поля должны быть приватными. Ограничений на область видимости полей в спецификации нет, главное - чтобы были публичные get и set методы. (На всякий случай, [ссылка на спецификацию, к сожалению на английском](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/)). Глава 2.2. пункт *Properties*

**Давайте рассмотрим пример:**
У нас есть база данных в которой есть таблица со статьями - articles с полями id (идентификатор статьи), content (содержимое статьи), published (опубликована ли статья)
Примером Java Bean может быть объект следующего класса:

```
public class Article implements java.io.Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private int id;
   private String content;
   private boolean published;

   // Конструктор по умолчанию
   public Article() {
   }

   // Аксессор для поля id
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }

   // Мутатор для поля id
   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getContent() {
      return content;
   }

   public void setContent(String content) {
      this.content = content;
   }

   // Для логического типа аксессор должен начинаться с глагола is, а не get 
   public boolean isPublished() {
      return published;
   }

   public void setPublished(boolean published) {
      this.published = published;
   }

}
```

на что в этом классе стоит обратить внимание - serialVersionUID, если его не объявить, то IDE будет выдавать предупреждение, но код будет компилироваться, и сериализатор сам сгенерирует значение для этого поля.

И раз уж мы заговорили о сервлетах, то пусть нашей задачей будет отобразить статью на web странице при помощи классической связки Servlet + JSP

для этого метод doGet сервлета будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    
    //Инициализируем статью
    Article art = new Article();
    
    //В оригинале значения свойств должны быть извлечены из базы данных
    art.setId(10);
    art.setContent("Одна из статей веб сайта");
    art.setPublished(true);
    
    //Теперь передаем наш Java Bean со статьей в аттрибуты запроса
    //Заметьте, в JSP странице он будет виден как article
    request.setAttribute("article", art);

    // Готовимся форварднуть запрос на страницу с отображением статьи
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("article_example.jsp");

    //Выполняем перенаправление
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

а сама страница article_example.jsp будет содержать такой код:

```
<div>${article.id}</div>
<div>${article.content}</div>
```

**Заметьте**, в JSP странице содержимое статьи мы достаем через `article.content`, а не `article.getContent()`, хотя, само поле `content` у нас помечено как `private`. Метод `getContent` будет вызван неявно, т.к. наш класс Article соответствует спецификации Java Beans.