# Что такое bean в Spring

Tags: java, spring

Не могу понять что такое Bean в википедии написано это как просто доменный объект, есть еще сервисы, контроллеры, DAO, что из них является бином и почему так называется, что я не так понимаю?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452633/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82-java-beans

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В Spring-е бином (bean) называют любой класс, который управляется контейнером Spring. То есть такими вещами, как создание экземпляра бина, его инициализация, внедрение зависимостей и параметров, деинициализация, генерация всевозможных оберток над бином, занимается не ваш код, а IoC-контейнер Spring-а.

Comment: Получается и сервис и domain и controller являются бином?

Comment: Если они болтаются спринговом контейнере - они являются *spring-бинами*.

Answer (score -5):

Ну по сути это класс с некоторыми ограничениями. 1)Конструктор используется без параметров. 2) Все поля private с доступом через геттер и сеттер.

Comment: Почему я объявляю сервис бином
    <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="kz.tanikin.springtest.service.MyUserDetailsService" />
почему не доменный объект не объявить, для чего он объявляется

Comment: Ни первое, ни второе, неверно. Может быть использован конструктор. Приватные поля могут инжектиться в случае использования автовайринга.