# В чём отличия обычного bean от bean в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, bean

Может быть вопрос сформулирован не совсем корректно, поправьте.
Я пытался найти определение bean, потому что столкнулся с тем, что определения в разных источниках разные.

Первое определение ([ссылка для примера](https://www.it-swarm.dev/ru/java/chto-takoe-javabean/969452452/)):
*JavaBean - это объект Java, который удовлетворяет определенным правилам программирования:
Класс JavaBean должен реализовывать либо Serializable, либо Externalizable,
Класс JavaBean должен иметь конструктор без аргументов,
Все свойства JavaBean должны иметь публичные методы установки и получения,
Все переменные экземпляра JavaBean должны быть закрытыми.*

Второе определение ([ссылка для примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455246/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-bean-%D0%B2-spring)): *В Spring-е бином (bean) называют любой класс, который управляется контейнером Spring.*

Плюс к этим двум определениям существует ещё таинственный Java EE Beans...

Целых три определения bean в одной Java!

И из-за этого возникла путаница. Очевидно, эти три определения отличаются *(причём по второй ссылке ответ, который содержал в себе определение из первой ссылки, заминусили)*.
Получается, первое определение справедливо для обычной Java, второе именно для Spring, а третье для EE? Тогда зачем обычные классы в ванильной Java называют бинами, если это обычные классы?

Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На базовом уровне JavaBeans-это просто классы Java, которые придерживаются определенных соглашений о кодировании. В частности, классы, которые

имеют открытые конструкторы по умолчанию (без аргументов)
разрешают доступ к их свойствам с помощью методов accessor (getter и setter)
implement java.io.Serializable

Spring bean-это в основном объект, управляемый Spring. Более конкретно, это объект, который создается, настраивается и иным образом управляется контейнером Spring Framework. Компоненты Spring определяются в файлах конфигурации Spring (или, в последнее время, с аннотациями), создаются экземплярами контейнеров Spring и затем вводятся в приложения.

Обратите внимание, что Spring beans не всегда должны быть JavaBeans. Spring beans может не реализовывать интерфейс java.io.Serializable, может иметь аргументы в своих конструкторах и т. д.

Это самое основное различие между JavaBeans и Spring beans.

Для получения дополнительной информации обратитесь к источнику приведенного выше текста, статье Шона Абрама JavaBeans vs Spring beans vs POJOs

Можно почитать [здесь](https://www.shaunabram.com/beans-vs-pojos/)

Comment: Спасибо. Осталось разобраться только с EJB. Довольно странно, что в пределах одного ЯП один термин имеет аж три значения. Впрочем, как и поток (stream), которым также называют входящий или исходящий поток данных, thread или stream API.